# socketserver TCPServer Error while deploying flask app to heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

Unable to solve this error. socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
[image]

Comment: Go to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to read more about how to ask a question.

Comment: The port you are trying to run the server on is used by something else. Not really sure about how it works, but you'll have to bind on the `$PORT` environment variable (`os.environ["PORT"]`), not whatever you want.